# Directory class not showing up in portable class library (PCL) using xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm creating a mobile android application and I put all non gui-related logic in a portable class library (PCL). Inside that library I'm trying to do the following

```
if (!Directory.Exists(path)) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory (path);
}
```

When building, the compiler says the Directory class is not found even when I imported the namespace (using System.IO) and checked that the reference is there, inside .Net portable Subset.

I tried do the same on the android project it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

A PCL whose targets include Windows Phone (which is the default profile for Xamarin iOS/Android PCLs) will not include System.IO classes, because Windows Phone does not support direct file IO.

Comment: I intend to use only android, at least for now. How do I configure the PCL to stop supporting windows phone? I'm using xamarin studio, by the way.

Comment: I don't think you can create an iOS/Android PCL that doesn't include Windows Phone.  If you're only interested in Android, then why bother with a PCL?  Just create an Android library project.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason pointed, that what I'm trying to do is not supported. From what I saw I had to options:

- Use an android class library project instead of a PCL
- Create an abstraction in the library and derive that abstraction in the android/Ios project.

In the end I decided to go for the first aproach since my project is android-only.